# How to parse date in Mat-Datepicker without moment

Tags: angular, angular-material, dayjs

In my Angular app, I have a problem with Mat-datepicker.
It does not parse the date in the correct locale when I type manually the date in the input field, but it is correct if I select it from the month view.

I have just switched to [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) from [moment](https://momentjs.com/) so I can't use the [moment-date-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material-moment-adapter) as I see in the docs.

Here the stackblitz with just the date field.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsvurg?embed=1&file=src/app/datepicker-locale-example.ts

Comment: Assuming you are pulling in the correct locale from dayjs, I found the easiest way was not to use a date adapter. I've only got one mat datepicker so thought all that code over the top. I ended up firing the (dateChange) event on the date picker and manually formatting  the date object in to a ISO string. Its really a one liner, but was all i needed as I stored the date as a string and parsed into a DateTime object on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I write my own adapter for dayjs, if you see something wrong feel free to correct me.
https://github.com/lippomano/material-dayjs-adapter/blob/main/material-dayjs-adapter.ts